# Rogue user on the loose.

Tags: discussion, etiquette

We have a [user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/5515/manimaran) who is very ecstatic about his recent WordPres [epiphany](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/your-most-memorable-programming-eurekas).  I surely know the feeling when the magical world of [programming unicorns](http://unicornify.appspot.com/) shine upon thee and everything all of a sudden makes sense.

This user got so excited he posted his [revelation](http://manisanjai.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/multiple-domains-with-single-wordpress/) to [every question he could find](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is:answer%20user:5515).  It's great to have enthusiastic users but I don't think it is possible that his theory (domain mapping) could be an appropriate answer for so many questions.

His code was also flawed and was run through wp_texterize along with a non standard character encoding.  (I edited and converted to UTF-8 and removed the HTML entities)

How do we [rein him in](http://www.preventingskynet.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Well... the effort is nice, but flooding with same answer without regards to context - not so much.

You caught me going afk, I will get to cleaning this up later today (unless other mod beats me to it) and decide if this warrants need to contact user directly about his behavior.

**Update** I had went over most answers and deleted those instances that had clearly no relevance or effort to fit actual question being asked.

PS to all - don't forget to exercise downvotes and flags on answers of poor quality, that way you help system learn and rely less on manual moderator intervention.

Comment: I copied and pasted my edit to all his answers so it doesn't look like we display code riddled with curly quotes and em dashes.